# Is Windows certificate store FIPS 140-2 level 1 certified?

Tags: fips, microsoft, mscapi

I'm not really aware of FIPS 140-2 requirements, but AFAIK some MS cryptographic libraries are FIPS 140-2 level 1 certified, so here it goes my question:

If I do have the following requirement:

> Signature private keys has to be stored in software/hardware complying
>   with FIPS 140-2 level 1.

And I do generate private keys on MS certificate store, am I complying my requirement succesfully?.

Comment: AFAIK MS certificate store uses Cryptographic Primitives Library (CNG) which are FIPS 140-2 Level 1 compliant. FIPS compliant policy needs to be enabled in Group policy. More information could be found over here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/fips-140-validation#modules-used-by-windows